# Records in JSONL file not uploading to BigQuery as record

Tags: google-bigquery

I am banging my head into a wall. I have a long data file in JSONL format that is being uploaded to BigQuery. For each entry there is a record of files information called 'files'. Things to note:

1. I have checked every entry of 'files' in JSONL and they are all entirely lists of dictionaries which BigQuery is supposed to recognize as a record
   ex.
   {"case_id": "abcd", "record1": [{"rec1_name":"rec1.txt"},{"rec1_name": "rec2.txt"}],"files": [{"file_name": "file.txt"},{"file_name": "file2.txt"}]
2. The table schema on BigQuery shows 'files' as a repeated record
3. The 'files' data in the BigQuery table is unnested despite both data source formatting and schema stating otherwise.
4. Other records in this data with almost identical structure work just fine (ex record1)

Anyone else have issues with uploading records to BigQuery like this?

Comment: Can you post the structure of the table and a couple lines of the file which fail?

Answer (score 0):

the code appears to be missing the opening and closing brackets `{}`. If your table is structured something like:

```
CREATE TABLE testing.json_nl (files array<string>);
```

Then your newline delimited json file needs to look like:

```
{"files": ["file.txt", "file2.txt"]}
{"files": ["file3.txt", "file4.txt"]}
```

If your table is structured with a `STRUCT` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE testing.struct_json_nl ( files array< STRUCT< file_name STRING> >);
```

Then your newline delimited json would look like this:

```
{"files": [{"file_name":"file.txt"}, {"file_name": "file2.txt"}]}
{"files": [{"file_name":"file3.txt"}, {"file_name": "file4.txt"}]}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have included more of an example entry. Each entry starts more like {"case_id": "abcd", "record1": [{"rec1_name":"rec1.txt"}],"files": [{"file_name": "file.txt"}]}. I've checked that it is already in the same format as previous records of data like "record1". That is why this is confusing for me